# long term recurrence relations and how to recorrect the deficit

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following question:

> In a sales drive a building society is trying to gain new customers. 
>   In any 6 month period it estimates that it loses 1.5% of its customers to
>   competitors and attracts 7000 new customers.  It has 0.5 million
>   customers at the start of its sales drive.

There are 2 questions:

> a) What would happen to the number of customers  in the long term if
>   this situation continued.
>   b) How many customers would the society have to attract in each 6
>   month period to maintain 0.5 million customers.

From the above, I can make the following sequence:

$${u_{n+1} = 0.985u_n + 7000}\text{ and }{u_0 = 500000}$$

Is there a better way of solving question a than using the ans function of a calculator and consistently press the equals sign to see what happens long term which to be honest is my current solution.

For question b, do I some how need to rearrange the equation to something like below and solve for a:
${u_{n+1} = 0.985u_n + a}$ and ${u_0 = 500000}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $u_{n+1}=au_n +b$, then we can easily see that:

$$\begin{align}
u_{n}&=b+ba+ba^2+\cdots +ba^{n-1} + a^nu_0\\
&=b\frac{1-a^n}{1-a} + a^n u_0\end{align}$$

Since $|a|<1$, the limit of this as $n$ approaches infinity is:

$$\frac{b}{1-a}  = 7000/0.015 = 466666.\overline{6}$$

The (b) question is far simpler - how many do you lose in a month? You have to  gain that many new customers.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what part of the question you are answering or what the above equation means.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to solve the recurrence relation
$$
  u_{n+1} = a u_n + b \qquad (1)
$$
where $a \neq 1$. Denote $l = b / (1 - a)$ the solution of the characteristic equation $x = ax + b$ of $(1)$, that is
$$
  l = a l + b. \qquad \text{(2)}
$$
Now, doing $(1) - (2)$ gives
$$
  u_{n+1} - l = a(u_n - l).
$$
This shows that the sequence $(v_n)$ defined by $v_n = u_n - l$ is geometric
with common ration $a$ and first term $v_0 = u_0 - l$, so
$$
  v_n = (u_0 - l) a^n,
$$
and then $u_n = (u_0 - l) a^n + l$, or
$$
  u_n = \Bigl(u_0 - \frac{b}{1 - a}\Bigr) a^n + \frac{b}{1 - a}.
$$